# Can python requests have hooks per sessions or global hooks?

Tags: python, hook, python-requests, portforwarding

I have a plan to use https://github.com/shellycloud/forwardmachine

And I want to use requests to contact those servers that were forwarded
I thought of using requests hooks, but I don't want to pass them in each request.

I want something global/session like this:

```
import requests

def forwarder_pre_request_hook(req, *args, **args):
   # do the trick I want, and replace the hostname and port of the url
   # I would still need to figure howto do it.
   return req

# globally 
requests.hooks = dict(pre_request=forwarder_pre_request_hook)

# per session
requests.Session(hooks=dict(pre_request=forwarder_pre_request_hook))
```

is it possible ?

Comment: look like I didn't read close enough the documentation [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Session.hooks). seems very possible

Comment: You need to read still closer: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/?highlight=hooks#event-hooks